# Remove all external resources from HTML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to remove all external resources from an html file.
I am using wget to make some local copies of a page. Wget has options to convert links to local file system and it is quite ok but still some links (at the end of the download depth I believe) keep their external src, so they contain http.

The closest I could get to find everything that contains http is using this:

doc.search("//*[starts-with(@href, 'http')]")

But that just finds the href elements and http can also in images, videos and anything.
Any ideas what would be the right instructions for Nokogiri to tell me everything that contains http?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to expand your search to elements with *any* attribute starting with 'http' you can do this:

```
doc.search("//*[@*[starts-with(.,'http')]]")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! For my needs I had to change it a bit to get exactly everything that contained http. But your code put me into track. I'm using now doc.search("//@*[starts-with(., 'http')]"

Comment: The difference is that my XPath statement (typo now fixed) finds all *elements* with any attributes starting with 'http', whereas yours finds just the *attribute nodes* themselves. Either is OK, it just depends on what you will be doing with the matches afterwards.